# DbContext not getting injected by autofac

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, autofac

I am having a problem where my context in not registering within my startup.cs

My complete startup looks like

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        RegisterApiTypes(builder);

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // Register your Web API controllers.
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        //Register filters
        builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    private static void RegisterApiTypes(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<Logger>()
           .As<ILogger>()
           .InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<ApplicationService>().As<IApplicationService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<CardRepository>().As<ICardRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        //tried both of these without any luck
        //builder.RegisterType(typeof(CustomContext)).As(typeof(DbContext)).InstancePerRequest();
        //builder.RegisterType<CustomContext>().As<DbContext>().InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("MyApp.Data"))
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    }

}
```

My context class is nothing special

```
public class CustomContext:DbContext
{
    public CustomContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
}
```

I try to inject the context in a standard manor

```
public MyRepository(CustomContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

However an error is thrown

> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'MyApp.Data.Repository.MyRepository' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:\r\nCannot resolve parameter 'MyApp.Data.CustomContext context' of constructor 'Void .ctor(MyApp.Data.CustomContext)'."

Has anyone else experienced this kind of behavior?

Comment: Repository is asking for `CustomerContext` directly in its constructor when you registered it as `DbContext`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Repository is asking for `CustomerContext` directly in its constructor when you registered it as `DbContext` so container doesn't know how to resolve `CustomerContext`

```
builder.RegisterType<CustomContext>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Answer (score 1):

Register `CustomContext` as `IDbContext` and the parameter to `MyRepository`'s constructor should be an `IDbContext`.

Comment: Sorry not sure I quite follow. Does CustomContext need to inheriate IDbContext and I then modify my repo?